# how to combine the theme with native html well

Tags: hexo

If we put html files in `_posts` folder, hexo will automatically combine html files and theme. The content of the html files is now the content of the new posts.

On the homepage, the titles of the posts generated are "Untitled". This is not I wanted. I hope that the titles of the posts are those of original html files. In addition, how to set excerpt, tags, and categories for this type of post? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use HTML directly in your markdown posts:

Create a `postName.md` file as you normally would.

And paste the HTML after the front matter

```
title: Your custom post title
date: 2013/7/13 20:46:25
tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']
---

<div>You can put whatever HTML you want here</div>
```

Comment: Your method does not work. I changed the html extension to md and then styles in the original html are broken. But if I use original html directly, styles are fine.